# Set Display of an element using .each() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This code is used to set display value of a collection of divs to `none` with an `if` condition:

```
$(".col-sm-4").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var allCategories = document.getElementsByClassName("ProductList");
        $(allCategories).each(function () {
            if ($(this).css("display", "block")) {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            }
        })
    })
```

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Snacks">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/XImages/snacks.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Baby">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/XImages/baby.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Perfumes">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/XImages/perfumes.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Then, I've multiple divs (all hidden). So if a user clicks "Snacks", its relevant div shows up.

```
<div class="ProductList" id="SnacksList" style="display:none">
<div class="ProductList" id="BabyList" style="display:none">
    Under construction
</div>
<div class="ProductList" id="PersonalCareList" style="display:none">
    Under construction
</div>
```

jQuery code used for accomplishing this is:

```
$(".col-sm-4").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = (this).id;
    var targetDiv = document.getElementById(id + "List");
    if (targetDiv.style.display == "none") {
        targetDiv.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            targetDiv.style.display = "none";
        }
})
```

Showing and hiding of a div with the relevant anchor button click is working fine, but only stops working if a relevant button is not clicked to hide a div and another anchor button (Category i.e., Perfumes) is clicked instead to show.

Hope this is making sense. Can someone please guide?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to use `.each()` while you need to hide all the elements with the class `ProductList` enough to say `$('.ProductList').hide()` .. BUT I think you don't want to hide all of them .. you may want to show/hide with the related click element .. If so .. you need to provide the relevant html as well

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - Haha. Relevant HTML is very messy. Be prepared. (Y) Updating it in my question in a lil while.

Comment: Just show a simple code which explain the relation between `".col-sm-4"` and `ProductList` which you mentioned in your question

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, I've updated my question. If you need more details, please ask.

Comment: `$('.ProductList').hide().filter("#" + id + "List").show()`    instead of all the code above

Comment: Can you show it in an answer below?

Comment: I posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Comments and OP updated you need to use `$('.ProductList').hide().filter("#" + id + "List").show()`

```js
$(".col-sm-4.rowitem").click(function (e) {
    var id = this.id;
    $('.ProductList').hide().filter("#" + id + "List").show()
});
```

```css
.ProductList{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Snacks">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/XImages/snacks.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Baby">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/XImages/baby.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Perfumes">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/XImages/perfumes.png" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="ProductList" id="SnacksList" >
    Under construction Snacks
</div>
<div class="ProductList" id="BabyList">
    Under construction Baby
</div>
<div class="ProductList" id="PerfumesList" >
    Under construction Perfumes
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `$(this).css("display", "block")` you are setting the property `display` to `block`. If you want to check the value on the property, instead you need to use `if ($(this).css("display") === "block")` or `if ($(this).is(":visible"))` if you are not looking at the particular value of `block`. More info about `JQuery.css()` can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1):

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var allCategories = document.getElementsByClassName("ProductList");

    $(allCategories).each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).css("display") === "block")
            $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ProductList">P1</div>
<div class="ProductList">P2</div>
<div class="ProductList">P3</div>
<button id="myBtn">Hide All!</button>
```

However, your code can be reduced, for simplicity, to next one if you wants to hide the visible elements with class `.ProductList` (assuming you are not looking at the particular value of `block` for the `display` property):

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".ProductList:visible").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ProductList">P1</div>
<div class="ProductList">P2</div>
<div class="ProductList">P3</div>
<button id="myBtn">Hide All!</button>
```

---

**Edit after question update:**

Another solution for you, could be using `data-target` attributes on the elements were you register the `click` handler, example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".ProductList").hide();
    
    $(".col-sm-4.rowitem").click(function(e)
    {
        $('.ProductList').hide();
        var target = $(this).data("target");
        $(target).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Snacks" data-target="#SnacksList">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=Snacks"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Baby" data-target="#BabyList">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=Baby"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Perfumes" data-target="#PerfumesList">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=Perfumes"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="ProductList" id="SnacksList">
    Snacks List
  </div>
  <div class="ProductList" id="BabyList">
    Baby list
  </div>
  <div class="ProductList" id="PerfumesList">
    Perfumes List
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why `e.preventDefault();` while the button doesn't have any default/redirect action?? .. And `:visible` in the OP case will not add more

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I left the `e.preventDefault()` because the OP has it in the captured click event over the `col-sm-4`, just in case it have any dessired effect on his code, but you are rigth, there is no reason for it on my code.

Comment: If the OP have event over event then he should use  `e.stopPropagation()` not `e.preventDefault()` ;) .. Have a great day :-)